# How to eliminate numbers that do not have different scrambled combinations within the range in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, integer

Prompt is 
Given integers A and B with the same number of digits and no leading zeroes, how many distinct scrambled pairs (i, j) are there that satisfy: A <= i < j <= B?

For instance, if we let A = 10 and B = 99, the answer is 36:

```
(12,21), (13,31), (14,41), (15,51), (16,61), (17,71), (18,81), (19,91), (23,32), (24,42), (25,52), (26,62), (27,72), (28,82), (29,92), (34,43), (35,53), (36,63), (37,73), (38,83), (39,93), (45,54), (46,64), (47,74), (48,84), (49,94), (56,65), (57,75), (58,85), (59,95), (67,76), (68,86), (69,96), (78,87), (79,97), (89,98)
```

This is my code:

```
import random
import itertools

A = input("Enter integer with no leading zero:")
B = input("Enter integer greater than A with no leading zero:")

A=int(A)
B=int(B)
realArray = []
myArray = []
temparray = []
heyArray = []
count = 0
totalcount = 0
printcount = 0
x = 0

def checkArray(myArray):
    global x
    global temparray
    for i in myArray:
        x = int(i)
        if x not in temparray:
            temparray.append(x)


  def allcombos(li):
    global count
    global myArray
    global realArray
    global heyArray
    global temp
    global printcount
    global A
    global B

    for subset in itertools.permutations(li, len(li)):
        s = ''.join(map(str, subset))
        if int(s) in range(A,B):
            myArray.append(int(s))
            if len(myArray)> 1:
               checkArray(myArray)
                myArray = []

def scrambleint(i):
    i_string = str(i)
    li = list (map(int, i_string))
    allcombos(li)



def main():
    for i in range(A, B):
        scrambleint(i)
    print (temparray)
    print(len(temparray))

main()
```

My output right now is 89

```
[10, 11, 12, 21, 13, 31, 14, 41, 15, 51, 16, 61, 17, 71, 18, 81, 19, 91, 20, 22, 23, 32, 24, 42, 25, 52, 26, 62, 27, 72, 28, 82, 29, 92, 30, 33, 34, 43, 35, 53, 36, 63, 37, 73, 38, 83, 39, 93, 40, 44, 45, 54, 46, 64, 47, 74, 48, 84, 49, 94, 50, 55, 56, 65, 57, 75, 58, 85, 59, 95, 60, 66, 67, 76, 68, 86, 69, 96, 70, 77, 78, 87, 79, 97, 80, 88, 89, 98, 90]
```

I want to get rid of numbers such as 10 and 11 from the list that don't have scrambled numbers within the range. (For example the only way to scramble 10 is 01 which is not in the range from A= 10 to B = 99). Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question looks like homework, but here is a one liner that can produce the required result:

```
from itertools import combinations
A = 10
B = 99
scrambled_pairs = [pair for pair in combinations(range(A, B+1), 2)
                       if pair[0] == (pair[1]%10*10 + pair[1]/10)]
>>> scrambled_pairs
[(12, 21), (13, 31), (14, 41), (15, 51), (16, 61), (17, 71), (18, 81), (19, 91), (23, 32), (24, 42), (25, 52), (26, 62), (27, 72), (28, 82), (29, 92), (34, 43), (35, 53), (36, 63), (37, 73), (38, 83), (39, 93), (45, 54), (46, 64), (47, 74), (48, 84), (49, 94), (56, 65), (57, 75), (58, 85), (59, 95), (67, 76), (68, 86), (69, 96), (78, 87), (79, 97), (89, 98)]
>>>> len(scrambled_pairs)
36
```

All this is doing is to iterate over all possible combinations of A and B and selecting those pairs for which `pair[0]` is the "reverse" of `pair[1]`.

Note: This is obviously tailored to your specific example. For a more general solution, change the filter/condition in the list comprehension to generically detect a scrambled pair, e.g:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def is_scrambled_pair(a, b):
    return tuple(str(a)) in permutations(str(b))

A = 10
B = 99
scrambled_pairs = [pair for pair in combinations(range(A, B+1), 2)
                       if is_scrambled_pair(*pair)]
>>> len(scrambled_pairs)
36
>>> scrambled_pairs
[(12, 21), (13, 31), (14, 41), (15, 51), (16, 61), (17, 71), (18, 81), (19, 91), (23, 32), (24, 42), (25, 52), (26, 62), (27, 72), (28, 82), (29, 92), (34, 43), (35, 53), (36, 63), (37, 73), (38, 83), (39, 93), (45, 54), (46, 64), (47, 74), (48, 84), (49, 94), (56, 65), (57, 75), (58, 85), (59, 95), (67, 76), (68, 86), (69, 96), (78, 87), (79, 97), (89, 98)]

A = 100
B = 999
scrambled_pairs = [pair for pair in combinations(range(A, B+1), 2)
                       if is_scrambled_pair(*pair)]
>>> len(scrambled_pairs)
1701
>>> scrambled_pairs[:100]
[(101, 110), (102, 120), (102, 201), (102, 210), (103, 130), (103, 301), (103, 310), (104, 140), (104, 401), (104, 410), (105, 150), (105, 501), (105, 510), (106, 160), (106, 601), (106, 610), (107, 170), (107, 701), (107, 710), (108, 180), (108, 801), (108, 810), (109, 190), (109, 901), (109, 910), (112, 121), (112, 211), (113, 131), (113, 311), (114, 141), (114, 411), (115, 151), (115, 511), (116, 161), (116, 611), (117, 171), (117, 711), (118, 181), (118, 811), (119, 191), (119, 911), (120, 201), (120, 210), (121, 211), (122, 212), (122, 221), (123, 132), (123, 213), (123, 231), (123, 312), (123, 321), (124, 142), (124, 214), (124, 241), (124, 412), (124, 421), (125, 152), (125, 215), (125, 251), (125, 512), (125, 521), (126, 162), (126, 216), (126, 261), (126, 612), (126, 621), (127, 172), (127, 217), (127, 271), (127, 712), (127, 721), (128, 182), (128, 218), (128, 281), (128, 812), (128, 821), (129, 192), (129, 219), (129, 291), (129, 912), (129, 921), (130, 301), (130, 310), (131, 311), (132, 213), (132, 231), (132, 312), (132, 321), (133, 313), (133, 331), (134, 143), (134, 314), (134, 341), (134, 413), (134, 431), (135, 153), (135, 315), (135, 351), (135, 513), (135, 531)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a second temporary variable to keep the individual elements of the integer to do this check like so:

```
temp2 = []
for t in temparray:
    m = map(int, str(t))
    if len(m) > 1:
        print m
        if 0 in m:
            print "0 caught"
            continue
        if m[0] != m[1]:
            temp2.append(t)
print temp2
print(len(temp2))
```

now my main() function looks like:

```
def main():
    for i in range(A, B):
        scrambleint(i)
    temp2 = []
    for t in temparray:
        m = map(int, str(t))
        if len(m) > 1:
            if 0 in m:
                continue
            if m[0] != m[1]:
                temp2.append(t)
    print temp2
    print(len(temp2))
```

Python is a beautiful language and what i did can be done in several ways, but this will solve your probem.

## My output:

[image]